# ¿Cómo accedo a una variable privada declarada en una clase, desde otra página?

Tags: php

Tengo una página que contiene un formulario con datos de clientes, dependiendo de la cantidad de clientes que tenga la consulta, muestra una tabla con 10 registros como límite, al tener más clientes, utiliza una paginación con botones para cambiar de página, mediante otro archivo, donde están declaradas clases que contienen las variables de cambiar de página. Dentro de los datos de los clientes, tiene un vínculo hacia otra página por cada cliente, dentro de esa nueva página, tiene un botón "Regresar" con una etiqueta input tipo "button", que hace la función de regresar a la página anterior, pero regresa hasta la página 1, lo que quiero es que regrese a esa página pero con el valor de la paginación donde seleccioné el cliente. Por ejemplo, hago una consulta, me muestra 26 registros de clientes, la tabla me muestra los 10 primeros y las opciones de cambiar de "paginación" donde, en la segunda, estarán los clientes número 11 al 20, y en la tercera del 21 al 26, hago click al registro número 16 que está en la "paginación 2", dentro de esa nueva consulta, está el botón de "regresar", al darle click, me regresa a la página en la "paginación 1" y lo que quiero es que me regrese a la "paginación 2" que es de donde seleccioné al cliente.
Deseo saber cómo acceder a la variable que contiene el número de paginación.

Este código es el de los botones para cambiar de paginación:

```
echo "      <table border=1 width=45% cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 align=center>";
echo "          <tr>";
echo '              <td><input type="submit" name="cmdPrimer" value ="|<"></td>';
echo '    <td><input type="submit" name="cmdAnterior" value ="<<" ></td>';
echo '    <td><input type="submit" name="cmdSiguiente" value =">>" ></td>';
echo '              <td><input type="submit" name="cmdUltimo" value =">|"></td>';
echo '              <td>' . $pagina_presente . '</td>';
echo '              <td> Total: ' . $total . '</td>';
echo '      <INPUT TYPE="hidden" NAME="id" VALUE="'.$page.'">';
```

Este código es del botón regresar al haber consultado al cliente respectivo:

```
echo '      <table border=0 width=70% align=center>';
echo "          <tr>";
echo "              <td align=center>";
echo '                  <INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="regresar" VALUE="Regresar" onclick="window.location.href=\'prosbusqueda_paco.php'\'">';      
echo "              </td>";
echo "          </tr>";
echo "      </table>";
```

Dentro del otro archivo .php donde está la clase que contiene la variable que quiero acceder tengo esto:

```
class ADORecordSet {
var $_currentPage = -1; /*Ésta es la variable que me dice en qué número de paginación me encuentro.*/
}
function AbsolutePage($page=-1)
{
    if ($page != -1) $this->_currentPage = $page;
    return $this->_currentPage;
}
```

Al hacer un "debug" en la página donde se encuentra la paginación, me muestra la variable "_currentPage", que indica al momento de cambiar de paginación, en cuál "paginación" se encuentra, es decir, en la "paginación 1", "paginación 2" o "paginación 3".

Espero alguien me pueda apoyar con este problema. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Que tal si intentas con javascript en el boton:
`<button type="button" onclick="javascript:history.back()"></button>`

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta, pero no lo hice con ese lenguaje, porque leí que es un tanto inseguro ya utilizar ese código.

Answer (score 0):

Debes hacer que la pagina reciba por $_GET, la pagina la pagina actual, y el numero de registros a  mostrar por pagina al dar clic a cada paginacion enviar al numero de pagina que deseas mostrar.

**registros.php**

```
<?php

$actual = isset($_GET['actual']) ? intval($_GET['actual']) : 1;
$mostrar = isset($_GET['mostrar']) ? intval($_GET['mostrar']) : 10;

$totalRegistros = $table->count();

$numeroPaginas = ceil($totalRegistros / $mostrar);

$end = $actual * $mostrar;
$start = $end - $mostrar;

$registros = $table->select($start, $end);

?>
<!-- Tu codigo html ... -->

<!--Inicio de tabla de regitros-->
<?php foreach ($registros as $registro): ?>
  <tr>
<!-- Impresion de registros ... -->
    <td><?php echo $registro['columna'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registro['columna1'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registro['columna2'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $registro['columna3'] ?></td>
    <td><a href="detalles.php?<?php echo "actual=$actual&mostrar=$mostrar" ?>"</a></td>
  </tr>
<?php endif;?>
<!--Fin de tabla de regitros-->

<!-- Inicia seccion de paginacion -->
<?php

for($i = 1; $i <= $numeroPaginas; $i++) :

$url = "./registros.php?actual=$i&mostrar$mostrar";
?>

  <a href="<?php echo $url ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a>


<?php
endif;
```

Para el caso de los detalles también pasa por $_GET los valores y crea un link para regresar enviando los valores que recibiste para mostrar la pagina de origen.

**detalles.php**

```
$actual = isset($_GET['actual']) ? intval($_GET['actual']) : 1;
$mostrar = isset($_GET['mostrar']) ? intval($_GET['mostrar']) : 10;

<a href="<?php echo "./registros.php?actual=$actual&mostrar$mostrar"?>">Regresar</a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si tuve que hacer una paginación nueva, para poder atrapar las variables, tu idea me funcionó, gracias.